# Where do I specify the appIdproperty that gradle is asking for?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am working on an app that uses appengine as its backend. I would like to download the backend server side code for my app using gradle's command line.

I type gradlew appengineDownloadApp at the command prompt and this is what I get

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app_server:appengineDownloadApp'.
>   No value has been specified for property 'appId'.

Where do I enter the appId? I am assuming this is the project id from my appengine account but I am unsure where to stick this value for gradle to read it.

Comment: I resolved my issue by downloaded the server side code for for the mobile backend starter appengine app from github tweaked it how I wanted to then uploaded it. I am now able to tweak it however I like and use gradle's awesome plugin tool to update it whenever I am ready to!

Comment: jamrockRay - can you provide more detail on this. If this worked, then it would be more helpful as a solution rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been looking for the answer and finally ended up on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin#convention-properties page:

```
The task appengineDownloadApp requires you to at least define the application ID and directory to write the files to. Define the tasks properties in the closure app:
  - id: The application ID.
  - version: The current application version (defaults to current default version).
  - outputDirectory: The directory where you wish to save the files (defaults to build/downloaded-app).
```

So the property "appId" in error message is a bit misleading... As described in plugin README, you only need to add to build.gradle:

```
appengine {
    app {
        id = 'your-app-id'
    }
}
```